# How to preload js workers and wasm scripts for offline use (pwa)?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, webassembly, offline-caching

I would like to force the browser to preload a JavaScript worker as well as a WebAssembly script. When loaded, I have a ServiceWorker that puts these scripts in the CacheStorage.

For the images, I use the following `<link>` tag and this works well:

```html
<link rel="prefetch" href="/img/foo.png" as="image" type="image/png" importance="low" />
```

So I tried the same things for my wasm and js scripts:

```html
<link rel="prefetch" href="/wasm/bar.wasm" type="application/wasm" importance="low" />
<link rel="prefetch" href="/js/baz.worker.js" as="script" type="text/javascript" importance="low" />
```

However, it looks like the Browser (Chrome) does not load these scripts with the `prefetch` rel. So I tried to use `rel="preload"`.

But I don't know what to fill for the `as` property for the wasm file and for the js worker file, I get the following warning: `` The resource http://localhost:3000/wasm/bar.wasm was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. ``.

If the user executes an action that requires these files, the browser loads them well and then we can use them when offline.

These scripts are not needed before the `load` event. I could send a fetch request when the browser emits the `load` event? But I think it is better to let the browser manages such things with a `link` tag? In my case, it is quite likely that the user will need this script (90%+), so a preload would make sense, but theoretically, I want to make a prefetch of the content only.

How would you recommend preloading these files for offline use (pwa)?

Comment: "But I don't know what to fill for the as property for the wasm file and for the js worker file" - for JS you've correctly set "script", and for Wasm it should be "fetch" since the module is fetched as any other binary resource before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sending an HTTP request with the `fetch` API puts well the script into the CacheStorage.

```js
/**
 * Preload resources for offline pwa use
 */
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  fetch('/js/baz.worker.js');

  fetch('/wasm/bar.wasm');
});
```

By sending these requests after the `load` event, it does not disturb the page load time.

To keep the priority hint, it is possible to set the importance parameter to low like the following:

```js
fetch('/wasm/bar.wasm', { importance: "low" });
```

(warning: limited browser support when this answer has been published)